# Service Broker with active stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, service-broker

I create a service broker by two SQL Server instances based on this link 
[enter link description here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/2797/)

Everything is ok, so my message is send by serverA as you can see :

```
Declare @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier

Begin Transaction
Begin Dialog @ConversationHandle
 From Service SenderService
 To Service 'ReceiverService'
 On Contract SampleContract
 WITH Encryption=off;
SEND 
      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      Message Type SenderMessageType
  ('<test>test</test>')
Commit
```

In Server B I receive the message using this code :

```
Declare @ConversationHandle as uniqueidentifier
Declare @MessageBody as nvarchar(max)
Declare @MessageType as sysname

Begin Transaction
Print 'Started Receiving ';

    RECEIVE top (1)
          @MessageType = message_type_name,
          @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
        @MessageBody = message_body
    FROM TargetQueue;

    if @MessageType = 'SenderMessageType'
          Begin
                SEND 
                      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
                      Message Type ReceiverMessageType
                      ('Message is received')
                END Conversation @ConversationHandle
          END

    Commit
```

This code receives the message, but for processing the message with this code I have to run the above code every time (manually). I want to make it automatic, I mean if the message is received, the above query is executed automatically.

Should I create a stored procedure with while 1=1 condition to process it?

Comment: Not unless you also look at [internal activation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281526).

Comment: @JeroenMostert your link uses WHILE (1=1)

Comment: Yes, but it also explains how to actually link up the stored procedure with the queue, which is the critical bit. Specifically, you should not be executing the stored procedure yourself.